# Unrecognized email address in the settings of community digests

Tags: discussion, security, email-notification, hacked, community-digests

Very recently, I visited the email settings of my account in https://stackexchange.com/digests.

To my surprise, I saw in the email settings an email address that I did't recognize (not belonging to me). I immediately, changed that email address and replaced it with my actual email address.

I should mention that I was subscribed to the digests of some of stackexchange sites in the past. But since some time I was not receiving these weekly digests (by contrast I was receiving filtered questions without problem).

Should I worry if my account has been hacked?

Comment: This... might need somewhat deeper investigation that meta would allow.  Could you use the contact form at the bottom of the page to log a ticket, referencing this post?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I filled the contact form.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I worry if my account has been hacked?

There is no way for anyone here to tell you if you were 'hacked' or not. You could've just misremembered which e-mail you entered, which is much more plausible than someone hacking your account just to change the e-mail address your account used to receive digests.

In any case, you shouldn't be worrying but taking action when you suspect something is fishy: don't just update the e-mail you used for the digests but also change your password, use the 'log out on all devices' option, then log in again with your new password.